# How to switch two frame present in a tab in python

Tags: python

```
class CustomerTab:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.tab = ttk.Frame(parent, width=800, height= 780)
        self.customer_history = ttk.Frame(parent, width=800, height=700)
        self.history_frame_button = ttk.Button(self.tab, text='Customer History', command=                    self.go_history)
        self.history_frame_button.place(x= 20, y = 400)

        self.back_tab_button = ttk.Button(self.customer_history, text= "Back", command=self.back_tab)
        self.back_tab_button.place(x= 20, y = 400)
        self.tab.place(x = 0, y = 20)
    def go_history(self):
        # self.tab.place_forget()
        self.customer_history.place(x = 0, y = 20)

    def back_tab(self):
        self.tab.place(x = 0, y = 20)

class RetailBillingGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Retail Shop Billing")
        self.window.geometry("800x600")
        self.window.resizable(False, False)

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.window)
        self.customer_tab = CustomerTab(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.customer_tab.tab, text="Customer")
        self.notebook.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

retail_billing_gui = RetailBillingGUI()
retail_billing_gui.run()
```

When I click on the Customer History button it switch the frame, but when I click on Back button the tab will vanished. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you tried to do in the `back_tab function` with `tab.place()`

A possible way to undo widgets is to `forget` them. There are various `forget functions` for each placement method ( grid, place, pack )

For your example I used `.place_forget()`

```
def back_tab(self):
    self.customer_history.place_forget()
```